# ahk - Get text after caracter (space)

Tags: regex, string, get, autohotkey

I'm new to Autohotkeys. I'm trying to remove all the text up to the first space on each line, getting everything else.

example:

```
txt1=something
txt2=other thing

var.="-1" " " txt1 " " txt2 "`n"
var.="2" " " txt1 " " txt2 "`n"
var.="4" " " txt1 " " txt2 "`n"
;; more add ...

FinalVar:=var
;...
msgbox % FinalVar
RETURN
```

Current output:

```
-1 something other thing
2 something other thing
4 something other thing
```

how I wish (all lines of FinalVar whitout need Loop):

```
something other thing
something other thing
something other thing
```

In bash i could use something like SED

Is there a fast way to do the same thing in ahk?

Thanks to your atention. Sorry my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [InStr](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InStr.htm) command

> **InStr()**
>   Searches for a given occurrence of a string, from the left or the right.
>   `FoundPos := InStr(Haystack, Needle , CaseSensitive := false, StartingPos := 1, Occurrence := 1)`

and [SubStr](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SubStr.htm) command.

> **SubStr()**
>   Retrieves one or more characters from the specified position in a string.
>   `NewStr := SubStr(String, StartingPos , Length)`

With InStr you find the position of the first space in var.

With SubStr you extract everything after that position to the end of the string like this:

```
StartingPos := InStr(var, " ")
var := SubStr(var, StartingPos + 1)
```

Note the + 1, it is there because you need to start extracting the text 1 position after the space, otherwise the space will be the first character in the extracted text.

---

To replace the leading text in all lines you can use [RegExReplace](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm)

> **RegExReplace()**
>   Replaces occurrences of a pattern (regular expression)
>   inside a string.
>
> `NewStr := RegExReplace(Haystack, NeedleRegEx , Replacement := "", OutputVarCount := "", Limit := -1, StartingPosition := 1)`

```
FinalVar := RegExReplace(var, "m`a)^(.*? )?(.*)$", "$2")
```

`` m`a) ``are RegEx options, `^(.*? )?(.*)$` is the actual search pattern.

> **m**  Multiline. Views Haystack as a collection of individual lines (if
>   it contains newlines) rather than as a single continuous line.
>
> **`a**: `a recognizes any type of newline, namely `r, `n, `r`n,
>   `v/VT/vertical tab/chr(0xB), `f/FF/formfeed/chr(0xC), and
>   NEL/next-line/chr(0x85).

Comment: Is possible remove this part of from final variable (all lines) in same time whitout a loop (many lines here)?

Comment: I was under the impression that you have control over each line, if you get only the final string maybe you should look into [RegExMatch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm)

Comment: I tried "FoundPos:=RegExMatch(var," ")" but the result looks with what your posted before (also get position of first line). How i can use this to get in all lines of FinalVar (in bash i will use sed)? Thanks to help..

Comment: try this `FinalVar := RegExReplace(var, "m`a)^(.*? )?(.*)$", "$2")`

Comment: It worked very well. But I had to add ` in (var, "m`a) as it was deleted in the post formatting. thank you!